# Excel Using SUMIF to sum and select higher numbers

Tags: excel, sum

I have the range of figures below

```
D                   E    
3000                6500    
20000               0    
15000               0    
16000               20000    
22000               0
```

I would like to take the total of column D but add the figures from column E to replace the corresponding value in column D if it exists. For example 3000 would be replaced by 6500 in the top line and 20000 would supersede 16000 in row 4.

I have been taking the sum of column d and manually subtracting D1 and adding E1 and D4 for E4 however as column E may be populated over time I would like not to have to do this over and over again.

Any help on this much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array formula should handle this nicely.

[image: Sum Maximum over two columns]

The *array formula* in D2 is,

```
=SUM(IF(A1:A5>B1:B5, A1:A5, B1:B5))
```

Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies and apols for lack of info / clarity initially. Using the array formula gets me to the answer I need. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Without array option:

```
=SUM(E:E)+SUMIF(E:E,0,D:D)
```

For *higher* numbers, you might add a column with a formula such as:

```
=MAX(D2,E2)
```

and sum that column.

Comment: While the sample data may be unclear on this point, what if E4 was 12,000?